# Linq-to-SQL Removing from ChangeSet

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have an `ObservableCollection<Widget>` that on `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` executes `context.Widget.InsertOnSubmit(addedWidget)`.

Before I execute `context.SubmitChanges()` I need to remove one of the added items as it is no longer needed, however there may still be items in `context.GetChangeSet().Inserts` that I still want to be inserted.

It it possible to cancel a particular insert/delete without throwing away the DataContext and starting again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After calling `context.Widget.InsertOnSubmit(addedWidget)` you can remove `addedWidget` from actually being inserted prior to `SubmitChanges` by using:

```
context.GetTable(Widget.GetType()).DeleteOnSubmit(addedWidget);
context.SubmitChanges(); // the insert simply doesn't happen.
```

This simply removes the `addedWidget` from the context it originally was going to add.  I would assume if you still have your `deletedWidget` you could then `InsertOnSubmit(deletedWidget)` and it won't be deleted.